# azure cognitive services - Parse US Mail Envelop image

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-services

I need help parsing a PDF document which contains text and different front images of US Mail envelops. This is advertising mail.  See attached image.

[image: front envelop]

From the Mail front image, I'd like to parse the return address and receiver address.   More complicated features: 1) randomly placed single or multi-line text 2) identify the font size and font name of #1  3) is there clear address window where the receiver address will be on the inside letter 4) the location of identified features.

Comment: So what did you do so far?

Comment: Microsoft Cognitive Services Computer Vision returns a JSON file with each consecutive word group as a parent node listed by its boundingBox coordinate ( upper left corner pixel coordinate )  In the above image, Node[x] = "Flip Over".   Node[x+1] = Mail To Name.   Node [x+2] = "to see your". Node[x+3] = Street Address.  Node[x+4] = "closest branch!".  Node[x+5] = City, State, Zip Code.  The 1st message context is Node[x], [x+2],[x[4].  The address context is Node[x+1], [x+3], [x+5].  There are many different layouts with more messages - there is no logical grouping rule.